# Problem installing nodejs version >= 10 on Linux Mint 19.3, which stubbornly installs nodejs 8.10

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, linux-mint-19

Trying to use https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md to install nodejs in version higher than 10 ( and then npm) on Linux Mint 19.3. It stubbornly installs the 8.10 version.

Tried fixing it with tip from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538536/newest-version-of-nodejs-is-not-intalling-in-linux-mint-tina but 1) "*check_alt "Linux Mint"    "tricia"   "Ubuntu" "bionic*" is already in the script 2) the result is the same.

Attempted to use sudo apt-get install as well as wget, which failed just like my last attempt, using the installation script downloaded:

```
dag@Arokh:~/Desktop/tmp$ sudo apt-get remove nodejs
[sudo] password for dag:                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 libhttp-parser2.7.1 libuv1 nodejs-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 18,0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 331148 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nodejs (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
dag@Arokh:~/Desktop/tmp$ sudo ./setup_10.x 

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 10.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]    
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]      
Ign:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com tricia InRelease                           
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease                    
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]    
Hit:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com tricia Release                             
Fetched 252 kB in 2s (137 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done

## You seem to be using Linux Mint version tricia.
## This maps to Ubuntu "bionic"... Adjusting for you...

## Confirming "bionic" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x/dists/bionic/Release'

## Adding the NodeSource signing key to your keyring...

+ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
OK

## Creating apt sources list file for the NodeSource Node.js 10.x repo...

+ echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
+ echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

## Running `apt-get update` for you...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]    
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease                    
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]      
Ign:6 http://packages.linuxmint.com tricia InRelease                           
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Hit:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com tricia Release                             
Fetched 252 kB in 2s (140 kB/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done

## Run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 10.x and npm
## You may also need development tools to build native addons:
     sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make
## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
     curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
     echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
     sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn


dag@Arokh:~/Desktop/tmp$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x bionic InRelease                    
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]      
Ign:6 http://packages.linuxmint.com tricia InRelease                           
Hit:7 http://packages.linuxmint.com tricia Release                             
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]
Fetched 252 kB in 2s (139 kB/s)                                   
Reading package lists... Done
dag@Arokh:~/Desktop/tmp$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4 845 kB of archives.
After this operation, 18,0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 331139 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Setting up nodejs (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
dag@Arokh:~/Desktop/tmp$ node -v
v8.10.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Node version 10

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl python-software-properties software-properties-common
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

But try to install the latest one as I can see the post is on Mar2021 and the Node version is 10, you may get a message like

```
                          DEPRECATION WARNING
```

Node.js 10.x is no longer actively supported!

You will not receive security or critical stability updates for this version.

You should migrate to a supported version of Node.js as soon as possible.
Use the installation script that corresponds to the version of Node.js you
wish to install. e.g.

- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x — Node.js 12 LTS "Erbium"
- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x — Node.js 14 LTS "Fermium" (recommended)
- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x — Node.js 15 "Fifteen"
- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x — Node.js 16 "Gallium"

Please see https://github.com/nodejs/Release for details about which
version may be appropriate for you.

The NodeSource Node.js distributions repository contains
information both about supported versions of Node.js and supported Linux
distributions. To learn more about usage, see the repository:
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

For Latest Release

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl python-software-properties software-properties-common
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo bash -
```

For LTS Release

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl python-software-properties software-properties-common
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -

$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ node -v
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed the steps described in the below link to upgrade, hope it helps:

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version

I chose the first option to Update Node.js with NVM (Node Version Manager)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Followed the linked procedure to use nvm. After executing "nvm install v14.6.0" more than half hour ago, the process is still going strong. I wonder if it's in a loop.

Comment: That was not the case for me. It installed instantly. I wonder if it is network related.

Comment: Eventually I installed Linux Mint 20.1 which installs a newer version of npm and node by default.