# nodejs 10 stubbornly installing in ubuntu 20 even after adding new verision ppa

Tags: node.js, installation, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install node.js latest version from node.js source official [github repo](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md). but after all running all commands yet, at `apt-get install nodejs`. system installs nodejs 10 version. I have already tried to [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421861/problem-installing-nodejs-version-10-on-linux-mint-19-3-which-stubbornly-ins). but even after running & installing `software-common-properties`. nothing changes.

**The error showing up when i run `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -`** is:

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 17.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Ign:1 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease
Hit:2 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release  
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease              
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease    
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

kindly help. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i was running `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -` in terminal. then the command was not succedding for some reasons and  failing (details below). due to that the nodejs version in the apt repo cache was not updating. so when i was installing `nodejs` by running `apt-get install nodejs`, it was always installing version `10`.

so **make sure that this command `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -` should run till end without any issue.** in the last if `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` line appears then `your apt repo cache is updated`. otherwise the command is failing.

###### The reason for failure in my case:

- i had `certbot installed` which had added a source in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. the problem was not with `certbot` install itself but with its **apt source url**. when `apt-get update` command was being run, then `certbot source` was being looked for which was not found on specified url. so it was causing `404` and  hence failure. so i went to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/certbot-ubuntu-certbot-focal.list` and commented all lines(only one line was active there). then again run the curl command. It worked this time.

##### so my advice is:

- **make sure curl command works properly**. for this i suggest to look for specific place where it is failing. I mean actually debug the script that is loaded from curl command. there are a lot of bash commands mentioned which is seting up everything.